# Mongoose.js Doc Refs - how to safely delete

Tags: mongoose

"The documents returned from calling populate become fully functional, removeable, saveable documents. Do not confuse them with embedded docs. Take caution when calling its remove method because you'll be removing it from the database, not just the array."

I find that a bit terrifying - how do you safely unlink a reference to a document in a mongoose document without deleting said document?

Comment: I'm curious about this too. Say I have a 'friends' array which contains a series of User documents. How can I unlink a document without actually deleting the user?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you're trying to do.  You can call `toObject()` on a Mongoose document to generate a plain JavaScript object representation of the document that's safe to pass around and modify without fear of accidentally altering the database.

Comment: I'm interested in this too, as i get it was meant deleteng an item from populated array without deleting this item from original collection, from which this array was populated. I want to store reference for particular doc for example, and due to my needs at some point i populated it. Now my reference is populated and if ill delete something out of its populated array and save i will end up deleting something from original population-donor array. It seems deleting/updating  meant to be used in depopulated state, but then, if use population - i need alway to use finOne if i want to edit a doc.

Comment: reference i mean jsut a simple variable. Like  `var reference;`
`Users.findOne(....functuon(err, founduser) { reference = founduser})`
And then if i lets say want to add something there, populate it and send out my reference will become populated and i will not be able to delete oe of the 'links for population' out of the array, cos it is populated and such an attempt will delete not a link but a linked item from db.
Maybe i just don't understand something, but seems that there is no way to store doc reference in variable and work with population.

Comment: @MaxYari As long as you don't call the `remove()` method on the populated docs, you can delete the docs from the array without side effects. If you need any more help, go ahead and post a new question.

Comment: in fact i'm already http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28727079/mongoose-node-js-how-to-find-populate-do-stuff-depopulate-and-update
Will be glad if you can look at it and get a grip of wha the hell i am talking about