# Mongoose/node.js how to find, populate, do stuff, 'depopulate' and update

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to make a nice and elegant call to db, but constantly suffer from lack of mongoose experience.

Hope i'm not too annoying, i'm trying to adress Stack Overflow only when my docs-google-Stack-digging skills fails.

What I want to do:

-find a doc in DB
-populate array inside this doc (this array in `Schema` is an array of `Objectid`s from `UserMeta` `Schema`)
-send it throug sockets to some better places
-update found doc with another `_id` reffering to doc in `UserMeta`
-save this updates to db & as future reference to var `currentroom`

Problem occures in last 2 steps, as i can't 'unpopulate' doc, that i already got as response and update-save it further.

For the moment that is how i'm doing this without any population:

```
Room.findOne({ Roomid: roomid }, function (err, oldRoom) {
    client.emit('others', oldRoom);
    oldRoom.UsersMeta.push(currentUser._id);
    oldRoom.save(function (err, newRoom) {            
        currentroom = newRoom;
    });
})
```

I can just brute-force-ish copy needed docs through toJSON from parrent `UserMeta` to this `Room` doc and just manually maintain both of them. But if there is a way to do this automagically via handy `mongoose` tools, I would like to take this way. And in the sake of curiosity, of course.

It's a continuation of my previous question [Saving reference to a mongoose document, after findOneAndUpdate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28720258/saving-reference-to-a-mongoose-document-after-findoneandupdate) -
just a remark, you dont really need to go there

Upd: Thing is that I need to run `populate()` In query with `findOne`, therefore in response I got `oldRoom` already with populated `_id`s

```
Room.findOne({ Roomid: roomid }).populate('UsersMeta').exec(function (err,       oldRoom) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    else if (oldRoom) {
        console.log(oldRoom.UsersMeta)
        client.emit('others', oldRoom.UsersMeta);
        oldRoom.UsersMeta.push(currentUser._id);
        oldRoom.save(function (err, newRoom) {
            currentroom = newRoom;
            console.log(newRoom);
        });
    }
    else { console.log('nothing found') };
})
```

upd2: so i figured out, that if i push new `_id` in already populated `oldroom` and save it, in db it will automagically appear as set of just `_id`'s as it should be. Yet I now confused if i will continue to work with this `currentroom` reference, as it was already pupulated, how can i safely remove something from populated array without removing populated entry from db completely.

upd3: Ah i just made a mess in my head. For some weird reason i thought that reference to doc saved in variable for each socket client will be always pointing to up-to-date doc in db, and that i will be able to work with this doc through it elluminating need to using find db tools more than once to get this reference... I need to rethink my db logic.
SO
There is a question then. If user connected to `Rooms` which is a doc from `RoomSchema`, and a user is a socket user i.e he has a personal scope in which i can store his personal session details. Can i somehow store direct link to this particular `Room` doc to elluminate need of searching for this room through whole db if user, for example, changes room's name. If i NEED to searh - it seems that it a better practice to save an id of room in which user is, and then just look up in db for room by this id and change it's name, am I right?

Comment: Can you please rephrase the problem, i am not sure what exactly the issue is

Comment: Well, i need to send, update and save `doc` after i found it. In the schema of this doc there is `UsersMeta: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'UserMeta'}],`. As I understand, to add another `_id` in the `UsersMeta`, which is a subject of population, and save the found `doc` i need it to be NOT populated. Yet, i need to send `UserMeta` out of found `doc` before saving, and it's must be populated.

Comment: you can delete UserMeta if you don't want it by delete newRoom.UserMeta

Comment: i want it inside `doc`, but presented only by it's `_id`, to be able to populate this `doc` again with those `UserMetas` in future, in fact on each this kind of call to db. Reason is to automatically track all changes in `UserMeta` collection. I.e if some of the `UserMetas` in room was changed in its original `UserMeta` collection i want just to call `populate()` on `Room` when its needed and got room with actual up-to-date `UserMetas` in it, that's why i need to save `Room` in unpopulated state, to be able to get updates to its `UserMeta` by population in future.

Comment: And as i understand i can not delete anything from mongoose doc through `delete something` anyway, only if i first convert it to `JSON/object`

Comment: yes. Also when you call findOne you get UserMeta in oldRoom and there ar e only _ids in that, if you want to keep it you can keep or delete it if you want to delete. I am still not able to figure what is the issue that you are facing

Comment: i will not gonna get oldRoom with only ids, as i will run query with populate,  which is the only way to populate as i know, correct me if i'm wrong.
Like this: `Room.findOne({ Roomid: roomid }).populate('UsersMeta').exec(function (err, oldRoom) {...`
Updated question to include this chunk of code.

Comment: No, thats not the only way; change the query like this;  Room.findOne({ Roomid: roomid },function (err, oldRoom) {...

Comment: this will give you UsersMeta with ids only

Comment: Then how will i populate this and do stuff with populated after it?

Comment: You should only be storing `_id` values in the user's session, not Mongoose instances.  Just look them up as needed. Finding a doc by its `_id` is incredibly fast.

Comment: Ahhhh... i just spent a whole day, dealing with something, that was COMPLETELY based of the assumption made in unicorn-land style. So, population+storing _id's than.
For the case if i want to delete a user from a room, what is the fastest way? Find a room by id, than somehow loop through users array and delete one, or there is a better solution?

Comment: And is there some particular reason to not use instances ever? for example it'll be pretty usefull to use `currentuser` instance of doc from `UserMeta` collection, which i get from creating this doc. This doc anyway will be updated only by this user, so its much more comfortable to use this instance to get data out of it when needed and cahnge data in it and `save()` to db instead of saving and maintaining data in this db doc and separate session object.

Comment: @JohnnyHK seems you wasnt notified of my previous comment, hope you can spend few minutes to look at them and clarify a bit for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query to get UserMeta with ids only

```
Room.findOne({ Roomid: roomid },function (err, oldRoom) {

});
```

Comment: That is exactly what i was doing before, as you can see in question, problem is how i will populate found doc inside this query for further operations with populated one?

Comment: as in example in mongoose doc http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html populate must be in the query, making this assumption out of this docs i wasnt even trying to call oldRoom.populate() maybe here is a catch, will try it in the moment

Comment: ok seems that i can call it like this `oldRoom.populate('UsersMeta', function(err, populated) {console.log(populated), console.log(oldRoom)})` yet now both `oldRoom` and `populated` are the same - i.e both populated, therefore i can not reuse unpopulated `oldRoom` further to update with new `_id` and save
.ah wait i made a mistake, checking

Comment: Rechecked, yes they are both getting populated.

Comment: well only way that i see now is firstly update, save, then populate, convert to JSON, somehow get rid of updated part and send to user.
I suppose if i push it to update i need just to get rid of last line in array.
If order of push i.e its normal behavior by adding to the end of array in mongoose doc is guaranteed